# Strange Double sum 3

Tags: calculus

Could you explain how to get the following double sum:
$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2 (-1)^{k+j}}{(j+1)^2 k!\, j! \left((k+1)^2+(j+1)^2\right)}=(\gamma -\text{Ei}(-1))^2$$ where $\text{Ei}$ is the ExpIntegral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
S
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^{k+j}}{k!j!(j+1)^2\left[(k+1)^2+(j+1)^2\right]}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+j}}{k!j!(j+1)^2\left[(k+1)^2+(j+1)^2\right]}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+j}}{k!j!(j+1)^2\left[(k+1)^2+(j+1)^2\right]}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+j}}{k!j!(j+1)^2\left[(k+1)^2+(j+1)^2\right]}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+j}}{k!j!(k+1)^2\left[(k+1)^2+(j+1)^2\right]}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+j}}{k!j!(k+1)^2(j+1)^2}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!(k+1)^2}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!(j+1)^2}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!(k+1)^2}\right)^2\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great David but it is something strange the third step in not well justicicate only by the symetry

Comment: @antonioasis The third step is just algebra. Find a common denominator.